# Is it good to to have high more that 99% accuracy on Decision Tree Classifier?

Tags: python, decision-tree

I am working on a Binary Classification problem which a dataset of 1 million. Dataset has 84 features and two target variables 'Normal and Bad' after encoding it is 0 and 1.

Without any features selection, I got 99.99900001, actually, I can't trust this score.
I have done StratifiedKFold with n_splits=10 splits I got 92.92% but I need to have above 97%. When am changing the n_splits=30, I got 98% accuracy from it.

Is n_splits=30 is good for 1 million datasets also can I use n_splits=30 ? Thank you.

here sample code of getting 99.999 accuracy

```
    from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, 
    y,test_size=0.30, random_state=4)

    model = DecisionTreeClassifier()

    model.fit(X_train, y_train)

    result = model.score(X_test, y_test)
    print('Accuracy: ',(result)*100)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don‘t tinker around with the performance measure to obtain a better value. Since you are obtaining widely different values with different numbers of splits in your cross validation, perform **repeated** cross validation to obtain a more robust metric.

In any case the goal should be to obtain a robust measure of the actual performance, not a high value if that value can’t be trusted. If 30-fold cross validation is fine depends on how much variation there is in your dataset. I‘d say it’s fine for your dataset size, but I can not definitely answer this without examining the dataset.

Comment: I'm working on the CICAndMal2017 Android malware dataset. Which has 2 types of targets One is Benign and the Other has the only attack. I have given a sample of .5 million Benign and .5 million Attack. On the internet, I have seen most of the time they use 5 or 10 that's why am not sure is 30 splits good or bad.

Comment: Do u need any other information @cherrywoods

Comment: As far as I know 10-fold cross validation repeated 10 times is standard. It’s probably a good idea to use this.

Comment: Today I have got accuracy from Random Forest 99.64 with confusion matrix, precision=1,recall=1,f1_score=1,  is it acceptable to have 1 in all? I don know why I am getting this type of confusing accuracy.

Comment: In general there is nothing wrong with having such high values. It just means that your model is performing very well. However, if your value is much higher than what is reported in the literature, there is probably something wrong. Btw, the website I found for CICAndMal2017 says that there are just 10,000 samples in the dataset. How do you obtain 1 mio samples from that?

Comment: My mistake, I mean 1 million raws with 84 features. I got it other researchers also found around 99.50 with random forest and Decision Tree. Thank you for your valuable time.